# How to add a Quadratic Sequence in an Array of Integers in C

Tags: c, arrays, integer, sequence

I'm trying to add a quadruatic sequence in an array of integers (in C), instead of typing it manually.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main () 
    {    
    int x [100] = {0, 50, 150, 300, 500, 750, 1050, 1400};
                //+0, +50, +100, +150, +200, +250, +300, +350, etc.
    return 0;
    }
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you need the array? You can simply calculate `hits(n) = 50 * n * (n+1) / 2`

Comment: could you elaborate more? what is n?

Comment: It's the array index. From your other question, it's the number of hits.

Answer (score 1):

num_add add 50 in each loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x[100];
    int num_add = 50;
    x[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        x[i] = x[i - 1] + num_add;
        num_add += 50;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%d ", x[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that code-only answers without any kind of explanation is discouraged because they tend to promote [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), which is bad. Please [read about how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for change main difference change the value of variable increment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x[100];
    int increment = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        x[i] = increment * i * (i+1) / 2
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%d ", x[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first time you add `D` difference,
but later difference continuously change.
change of that difference is in arithmetic progression
increment of main difference `D` is `C` constant

In your case both `D` & `C` are same, 50.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x[100];
    int D = 50;
    int C = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        x[i] = (D*i) + (C*i*(i - 1))/2
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%d ", x[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if `C == D` (as your case), replace one variable

```
x[i] = (D*i) + (C*i*(i - 1))/2
     = (D*i) + (D*i*(i - 1))/2
     = D * i * ( 1 + (i - 1)/2 )
     = D * i * (2 + (i - 1)) / 2
     = D * i * (i + 1) / 2
x[i] = D * i * (i+1) / 2
```